# Confusion about formula for Linear regression with gradient descent, (Pseudocode)

Tags: gradient, linear-regression

I'm made a program that calculates the line of best fit of a set of data points using gradient descent. I generate a 1000 random points and then it calculates the line of best fit training on these 1000 points. My confusion lies in the theory of my code.

In the part of my code where the training function is, by using the current m and b values for  y= mx +b, the function makes a guess of the y values when it goes through the training points x values. This is supervised learning, so I know what the actual y value is, the function calculates the error and using that error adjusts the m and b values. <-- What is happening in the program when adjusting the line of best fit

I get everything above ^. what I'm confused about is the part of the code that calculates how to adjust these m and b values. Here it is:

```
    guess = m * x + b;
    error = y - guess;
    m = m + (error * x) * learningrate;
    b = b + error * learningrate;
```

Im confused about why we add instead of subtract that delta m (the (error * x) *learningrate)) part. Ignoring the learningrate, the error * x part is the partial derivative of the error with respect to m. But if we took the partial derivative of something with respect to something, wouldn't it give us the direction of the steepest ascent? Shouldn't we go the opposite direction (subtract the delta m) to get the proper m value? Isn't our goal to reduce the error?

Surprisingly to me, the above code works, if you add the delta m, it adjusts the m and b values in the right direction. So basically my question is: Why aren't we subtracting the delta m part (error *x) as it is pointing in the direction of steepest ascent, and we want to get the opposite of that?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been browsing around other question to see if anybody else has the same confusion. I found this website from Carnegie Mellon: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15381-s06/www/nn.pdf They updated their m and b values by SUBTRACTING the delta m and bs, but in the next slide, they went back to adding the delta m and bs, I'm getting very confused.

Comment: Hi, I haven't gotten a reply and was wondering if anybody was confused about my question?